# how to follow a list of splines one after another

Tags: animation-nodes

i try to follow a list of splines with a "emitter mover" - one after another.

I did this with animation nodes (image below)

result: the first spline works well and moves along the first spline.
the second "jumps" to the starting point of spline 2 and stays there instead of moving along the spline.
the third "jumps" to the starting point of spline 3 and stays there instead of moving along the spline.

what am i doing wrong?

update: i know, how to connect splines - i don't want that to use, because i need them "splitted"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]After playing a while with the nodes you have used, I discovered that the *Object Action Output Node* expects to start with frame 1 for each subsequent action. You might put a math-node with *Modulo* selected between *Time Per Char Node*(b)  plus * *(a) and the *Frame* input from the *Object Action Output Node* to get what you want.